# One domain can not see other domain - possible DNS issue

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I believe I have a fairly simple question that most likely relates to a DNS issue.

I have two domains for explanation purposes I will refer to them as DOMAIN1 and DOMAIN2

DOMAIN1 = 2008 R2 Enterprise
DOMAIN2 = 2012 R2

DOMAIN1 is able to see DOMAIN2 but DOMAIN2 can’t see DOMAIN1. I noticed this because I am trying to install and antivirus program and it is unable to reach the domain.

From everything I’ve read this appears to be a DNS issue, but I’m unable to find a solution. Here’s my settings:

***DOMAIN1:***

IP: **192.168.1.204**

Preferred DNS: 127.0.0.1

Alternate DNS: 205.171.3.65

DNS server in order of use: 127.0.0.1 / 205.171.3.65 / 205.171.2.65 / 204.117.214.10 / 204.97.212.10 / 208.67.222.222 / 208.67.220.220 / **192.168.1.203**

***DOMAIN2:***

IP: **192.168.1.203**

Preferred DNS: 127.0.0.1

Alternate DNS: 208.67.222.222

DNS server in order of use: 127.0.0.1 / 208.67.222.222 / 208.67.220.220 / **192.168.1.204** / 205.171.3.65 / 205.171.2.65 / 204.117.214.10 / 204.97.212.10

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using external DNS servers on your internal machines? That's not correct. How are you trying to "see" one domain from the other? Do you mean by browsing the network? Do you mean by querying DNS? Do you mean by querying the NetBIOS name?

Comment: nslookup domain1 from domain2 and see if it resolves with a list of DCs

Answer (score 1):

Do a conditional forwarder on DOMAIN1 DNS Server pointing to DOMAIN2 and add the Primary DNS IP Address for Domain2. Then do the same from DOMAIN2 primary DNS. This will point the dns server at Domain1 to look at domain2 dns server when doing a query and vice versa.